# MySQL + PHP: select multiple rows on a join, then update those rows/insert new ones

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to do the following:

1. Select **multiple** rows on an INNER JOIN between two tables.
2. Using the primary keys of the returned rows, either:

   1. Update those rows, or
   2. Insert rows into a different table with the returned primary key as a foreign key.
3. In PHP, echo the results of step #1 out, ideally with results of #2 included (to be consumed by a client).

I've written the join, but not much else. I tried using a user-defined variable to store the primary keys from step #1 to use in step #2, but as I understand it user-defined variables are single-valued, and my SELECT can return multiple rows. Is there a way to do this in a single MySQL transaction? If not, is there a way to do this with some modicum of efficiency?

**Update**: Here are the schemas of the tables I'm concerned with (names changed, 'natch):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `widgets` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`author` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`updated` timestamp 
          NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `downloads` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`widget_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`lat` float NOT NULL,
`lon` float NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I'm currently doing a join to get all widgets paired with their downloads. Assuming `$author` and `$batchSize` are php vars:

```sql
SELECT w.id, w.author, w.text, w.created, d.lat, d.lon, d.date
FROM widgets AS w
INNER JOIN downloads AS d
ON w.id = d.widget_id
WHERE w.author NOT LIKE '$author'
ORDER BY w.updated ASC
LIMIT $batchSize;
```

Ideally my query would get a bunch of widgets, update their `updated` field OR insert a new download referencing that widget (I'd love to see answers for both approaches, haven't decided on one yet), and then allow the joined widgets and downloads to be echoed. Bonus points if the new inserted download or updated widgets are included in the echo.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like this can be done in one SQL query - care to share some of your code or schema so we can have a go at writing it? Otherwise it's all theoretical...

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes to get a schema up there.

Comment: Added schemas and my current query.